# How to add the numbers from a user's input

Tags: python

So I am trying to get a user's input and add it's numbers together.

```
input('Enter number: ')
```

And then say the user entered 458 then I wanted to add all it's digits up? I have tried using + but it doesn't work. Any solutions?

Comment: "I have tried using + but it doesn't work."—Specifically, how did you try using `+`? What does "doesn't work" mean? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

The problem you probably came across is that you have a string.

```
>>> answer = input('Enter number: ')
Enter number: 458
>>> print(type(answer))
<class 'str'>
```

But if you want to add each of the digits up, you'll need to convert each digit to an int. Thankfully, because we have a string here, we can actually iterate through each character in the string (try not to read it as "each digit in the number", because we have a string `'458'` here with characters `'4'`, `'5'`, `'8'`.)

```
>>> total = 0
>>> for character in answer:
...     total = total + int(character)
... 
>>> print(total)
17
```

Notice how I convert each character in the string to an integer, then add it to a total integer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work:

```
user_number = input('please enter your number')


sum = 0
for num in user_number:
    sum += int(num)

print(sum)
```

Comment: It says int object is not iterable.

Comment: @Anonymousisme, I guess you're using Python 2, not Python 3? In that case, use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. Also, consider upgrading since [Python 2 is no longer receiving support](https://pythonclock.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your input into a list then use list comprehension:

```
num = input('Enter number: ')
sum([int(i) for i in num])
```